# Error 1119 when using Inspectable in class extending a parent also with Inspectable properties

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

**Short description:**

I have a class C which is extending a class P. Class P has a few Inspectable properties.

I added a few Inspectable properties to class C, linked C to a component in library and added C as the class of the Component Definition of that component. I could, at that point, read and set the Inspectable properties(that belong to P and C) of the instances of that component that were on stage through Component Parameters section of Properties window.

However, if I set even a single Inspectable property of class C through Component Parameters, when I try to export an .swf, I get a different compiler error 1119 for each Inspectable property of C(even if I did not set it and left its default value), saying that I am referencing possibly undefined property *childProperty* through a reference with static P.

**Detailed description:**

I have a class ChildClass, which extends a class ParentClass and I am trying to declare a few **public** attributes of ChildClass as Inspectable. ParentClass, too, has a few Inspectable getters and setters helping access corresponding **protected** attributes in the parent.

For the sake of completeness, consider that there is an inspectable property of **ChildClass** named **childProperty**. Consider also that there is an object of type **ContainingClass** which has a **public** attribute **childClassInstance** of type **ChildClass**. **ContainingClass** is linked to a library component which does have a **ChildClass** instance as a child. Finally, note that **ChildClass** is in **samplePackageB.a** while **ParentClass** is in **samplePackageA**.

So the code looks like this:

```
    package samplePackageA
    {
        public class ParentClass extends MovieClip
        {
            protected var _parentValue:String;
            [Inspectable(defaultValue="")]
            public function get parentValue():String { return _parentValue; }
            public function set parentValue(value:String):void {
                _parentValue = value;
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    package samplePackageB.a
    {
        import samplePackageA.ParentClass;
        public class ChildClass extends ParentClass
        {
            [Inspectable(defaultValue="1.0")]
            public var childProperty:Number;
            ...
        }
    }

    package samplePackageB.b
    {
        import samplePackageB.a.ChildClass;
        public class ContainingClass extends MovieClip
        {
            public var childClassInstance:ChildClass;
            ...
        }
    }
```

I added **ChildClass** to the Component Definition of a library component. and I could read/set inspectable properties of both **ParentClass** and **ChildClass** in the Component Parameters of an instance of that library component which was on stage.

However, when I try to export a .swf of this .fla file, I get **compiler error 1119**, stating that I am "accessing (of) possibly undefined property **childProperty** through a reference with static type **ParentClass**".

The only similar issue I found can be viewed [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1468298?start=0&tstart=0) but it seems it wasn't conclusively solved(or explained) then, either.

Comment: [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/453659?tstart=0) speaks about adding a tag in the subclass for all properties in the superclass among other things, maybe that helps

Comment: I had already tried that before posting this question. Sadly, it did not help. I ended up having to add the inspectable attributes to a class containing the instance(s) of ChildClass and have ChildClass retrieve the set values by invoking relevant methods in its parent Object. It is by no means a pretty solution, but it is the least time consuming temporary fix I could come up with at the time.